# Azure ML Studio in Azure Stack

Tags: azure

Can some one please tell me if we can have Azure ML Studio available in Azure Stack.
I have requirement to install azure stack and then build some of experiments using Azure ML Studio.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Azure ML Studio is not available in Azure Stack. The unique Machine Learning item available is *Microsoft Machine Learning Server*:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-stack/azure-stack-marketplace-azure-items

- Microsoft Machine Learning Server 9.3.0 on Windows Server 2016
- Microsoft Machine Learning Server 9.3.0 on Ubuntu 16.04
- Microsoft Machine Learning Server 9.3.0 on CentOS Linux 7.2

Exist a feedback request about Machine Learning on Azure Stack:

https://feedback.azure.com/forums/257792-machine-learning/suggestions/13253103-add-machine-learing-to-azure-stack